# How to use Orthoengine in PCI Geomatica to georeference Pleiades 1B TIFF to WGS 84

Tags: raster, georeferencing, geomatica

I am trying to use the orthoengine in PCI Geomatica 2015 to reference an image to WGS 84 (ESPG: 4326).

Acquisition mode PX
Spectral processing PA+XS (resolution is 70cm)

I have the associated RPC file.

The problem I have is that when I try to set the projection to that in the RPC file (WGS 84) I get an error message stating that the output georeferencing must be projectable.

Any suggestions?[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to dublicate your example. 
Using the same projection settings the dialoog completes with no errors.
What option did you choose at the previous step? are you making a rational model or a polynomial?

I would choose projection D000 (WGS84 meters, in PCI) and not E012 which is rather the datum than the projection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the Set projection. When you load you DIM file (metadata), it gives to automatically the projection.